# how to create 100 vectors in R in one go, and combine them all into one dataset

Tags: r

I have a list in my workspace named “sample_experiment”, from which I need to draw some information in the form of vectors, like this:

```
first_column <- sample_experiment[[1]]$latent

second_column <- sample_experiment[[2]]$latent

third_column <- sample_experiment[[3]]$latent

# And so on, up to

hundred_column <- sample_experiment[[100]]$latent
```

Each vector (column) would contain 10 different numerical values.

The question is, to suggest a code to create all 100 vectors (columns) in one go, as it is obviously unfeasible to manually type all 100 vectors? Also, to combine all created 100 vectors into a dataframe with 10 rows and 100 columns?

Comment: checkout `(t|s|l)apply` functions family in base R.

Comment: Ohh I am sorry it is base R, not `tidyverse` it has been a while since I used R. As @Adam suggests, `map_*` functions from `purrr` is a good choice as well (not entirely sure but could be faster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making a bit of an assumption on your data format, but perhaps this will work using `purrr`.

```r
sample_experiment <- replicate(100, list(data.frame(latent = runif(10))))

library(purrr)

sample_experiment %>% 
  set_names(~ paste0("column_", seq_along(.))) %>% 
  map_dfc( "latent")
```

You can also make use of base R.

```r
as.data.frame(lapply(sample_experiment, `[[`, "latent"),
              col.names = paste0("column_", seq_along(sample_experiment)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, if your columns can be called `column_N`:

```
sample_experiment <- list(
  data.frame(latent = c(1:10)),
  data.frame(latent = c(11:20)),
  data.frame(latent = c(21:30))
)

names_vec <- paste0("column_", 1:3)

all <- setNames(cbind.data.frame(lapply(sample_experiment, function(x) x[['latent']])), names_vec)

# tidyverse approach
library(tidyverse)

all <- map_dfc(sample_experiment, ~.x %>% select('latent')) %>% 
  set_names(nm = names_vec)
```

For this example, it returns:

```
   column_1 column_2 column_3
1         1       11       21
2         2       12       22
3         3       13       23
4         4       14       24
5         5       15       25
6         6       16       26
7         7       17       27
8         8       18       28
9         9       19       29
10       10       20       30
```

Comment: This works nicely, but perhaps make it flexible.. what if each of the elements (in your example data.frames) within `sample_experiment` has multiple columns, one of which is called `latent`?  This would add additional (unwanted) columns to the output.

Comment: Yeah, good call. I updated my answer and added a `tidyverse`/`purrr` approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(1:100, \(i) sample_experiment[[i]]$latent))
```

If you want the output as a frame with named columns ("col1", "col2"..etc), just wrap the above in `setNames(as.data.frame())`, as below:

```
setNames(
    as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(1:100, \(i) sample_experiment[[i]]$latent))),
    paste0("col",1:100)
)
```

Comment: Thank you all guys for your awesome suggestions! They all worked!)